# Xamarin MediaPicker CapturePhotoAsync restarting the app after pressing "Ok" button and throwing silent error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been experiencing an error while using the XamarinEssentials.MediaPicker CapturePhotoAsync() method. Some users of an application of mine have been going through silent crashes that restarts the app without logging anything to the appCenter right after accepting the picture that was taken. (video of the error attatched [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oCXHTNEOc-K_FXaUL2xhMym8LBJ0nijh/view?usp=sharing) ). Note that this video was taken by a user that holds a Xiami Redmi Note 9S and I do not have access to this device. I could not manage to reproduce this error on any device that I have tested. Not in development Mode nor Release.

Appearently it is some bug going inside MediaPicker code that consumes all the available RAM of the device, forcing it to restart.

I have seen a lot of other reports on the internet but any of them would come up with a conclusion or a solution.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Find Below the entire code envolved in capturing the picture and also post-processing it, envolving resizing the image, rotating it, saving it to gallery and also save a thumbnail.

```
public async Task TakePicture(object param)
    {
        var permissionsOk = await VerifyPermissions();
        if (!permissionsOk) return;

        try
        {
            var options = new MediaPickerOptions
            {

            };
            var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
            await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
            Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync COMPLETED: {PhotoPath}");
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            // Feature is not supported on the device
            var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Função:", "TakePicture" },
                    { "Arquivo:", "VisitDetailsRegistrationViewModel"},
                    { "Observação", "FeatureNotSupportedException"}
                };
            Crashes.TrackError(fnsEx, properties);
        }
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {
            // Permissions not granted
            var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Função:", "TakePicture" },
                    { "Arquivo:", "VisitDetailsRegistrationViewModel"},
                    { "Observação", "PermissionException"}
                };
            Crashes.TrackError(pEx, properties);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "Função:", "TakePicture" },
                    { "Arquivo:", "VisitDetailsRegistrationViewModel"},
                    { "Observação", "Exception"}
                };
            Crashes.TrackError(ex, properties);
        }
    }

    async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
    {
        // canceled
        if (photo == null)
        {
            PhotoPath = null;
            return;
        }

        var meta = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(await photo.OpenReadAsync());
        var subIfd0Directory = meta.OfType<ExifIfd0Directory>().FirstOrDefault();
        var orientation = subIfd0Directory?.GetDescription(ExifDirectoryBase.TagOrientation);
        var rotationAngle = GetRotationAngle(orientation);

        // save the file into local storage
        var newFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var imageByteArray = ReadFully(stream);
            //var resizedImageByteArray = ResizeImage(imageByteArray, 2000, 2000, 92);
            var rotatedImageByteArray = RotateImage(imageByteArray, rotationAngle, 92);
            //var mediaService = DependencyService.Get<IMediaService>();
            //mediaService.SaveImageFromByte(rotatedImageByteArray, photo.FileName);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(rotatedImageByteArray))
            {
                using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
                {
                    await ms.CopyToAsync(newStream);
                }
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(rotatedImageByteArray))
            {
                try
                {
                    await MediaGallery.SaveAsync(MediaFileType.Image, ms2, photo.FileName);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "Função:", "LoadPhotoAsync" },
                        { "Arquivo:", "VisitDetailsRegistrationViewModel"},
                        { "Observação", "Exception"}
                    };
                    Crashes.TrackError(ex, properties);
                }
            }
        }
        PhotoPath = newFile;

        var thumbFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "Thumb-"+photo.FileName);
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var thumbByteArray = ReadFully(stream);
            var resizedThumbByteArray = ResizeImage(thumbByteArray, 500, 500, 92);
            var rotatedThumbByteArray = RotateImage(resizedThumbByteArray, rotationAngle, 92);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(rotatedThumbByteArray))
            {
                using (var newStreamThumb = File.OpenWrite(thumbFile))
                    await ms.CopyToAsync(newStreamThumb);
            }
        }
        ThumbPath = thumbFile;
    }

    public int GetRotationAngle(string orientationText)
    {
        if (orientationText == null) return 90;

        if (orientationText.Contains("90")) return 90;
        else if (orientationText.Contains("180")) return 180;
        else if (orientationText.Contains("270")) return 270;
        else return 0;
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] RotateImage(byte[] imageData, float degrees, int quality)
    {
        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);

        var matrix = new Matrix();

        matrix.PostRotate(degrees);

        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height, matrix, true);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            rotatedBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, quality, ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] ResizeImage(byte[] imageData, float width, float height, int quality)
    {
        // Load the bitmap
        Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);

        float oldWidth = (float)originalImage.Width;
        float oldHeight = (float)originalImage.Height;
        float scaleFactor = 0f;

        if (oldWidth > oldHeight)
        {
            scaleFactor = width / oldWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            scaleFactor = height / oldHeight;
        }

        float newHeight = oldHeight * scaleFactor;
        float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

        Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(originalImage, (int)newWidth, (int)newHeight, false);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            resizedImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, quality, ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do any of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69284163/199364) help? Some other related threads google `site:stackoverflow.com mediapicker capturephotoasync restarting app`. I can't find the thread, but be sure to **put all large bitmaps into `drawable-nodpi`:** some high-density devices "scale up" all bitmaps in the normal `drawable` folder; even when that makes no sense. Resulting in memory problems.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the prompt response! I did bump into this link that you mentioned and will try the snippets available! I also updated my question and posted all the code that comes after the MediaPicker method and image processing that I have been doing. It may help someone else or even help the community find any mistake or possible improvements that may help with memory consumption.

Comment: I realized that I have been placing the Image in the cache directory, do you think that may be somehow related to this intermitent issue?

Comment: I don't know. I just know about image resources, drawable vs drawable-nodpi.

Answer (score 3):

To date this bug is not fixed in any of the Xamarin photo capture libraries. It is caused by the fact that the callback Task is stored in memory, so when Android decides it needs to free resources while the camera app is in the foreground, the app is closed, and the callback is lost.

When the user has taken the photo, the app is restored, but within OnActivityResult there is no way to call back into the code to handle the photo. Currently there doesn't look like any way to handle this scenario.